# How can I test WS2812B 5 m 60 LEDs/m with NodeMCU?

Tags: nodemcu, ws2812b

I bought this WS2812B 5 m 60 LEDs/m. I want to know if it works properly. I have a NodeMCU 1.0 and I recently bought a 5 V, 10 A adaptor for these but the damn thing still only lights up the first LED to white and nothing further.

I have tried the following code (it's from examples only).

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define LED_PIN 12 //means pin D6 on NodeMCU1.0

#define LED_COUNT 300

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
  strip.setBrightness(50);
}

void loop() {
  colorWipe(strip.Color(255,   0,   0), 50); // Red
  colorWipe(strip.Color(  0, 255,   0), 50); // Green
  colorWipe(strip.Color(  0,   0, 255), 50); // Blue

  rainbow(10);
}

void colorWipe(uint32_t color, int wait) {
  for (int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) { 
    strip.setPixelColor(i, color);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

void rainbow(int wait) {

  for (long firstPixelHue = 0; firstPixelHue < 5*65536; firstPixelHue += 256) {
    strip.rainbow(firstPixelHue);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}
```

Connection wise I have connected the + terminal of the 5 V, 10 A to the Vin of the NodeMCU and also + terminal of the strip, and - to the GND and - of the LED strip; nothing else really is needed so I haven't added.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKgbbs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any suggestions or insights will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a scope?

Comment: WS2812B expects 5V signals, you may need a proper line driver IC.

Comment: Check if you connected a proper side of strip.

Comment: I am connecting the right side of strip, @user263983 I think the backside of arrow on data pin.

Comment: So more current is needed? @Jens? I will try with 5V 20A now. I think 10A won't cut for 5m, that's 300 LEDs approx.

Comment: No, my idea was, that the 3.3 V digital output is not high enough to be understood by the WS2812B. Here is a clever solution: https://hackaday.com/2017/01/20/cheating-at-5v-ws2812-control-to-use-a-3-3v-data-line/